# How to find broken links using Selenium WebDriver with Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to verify broken links on a website and I am using this code:

```
 public static int invalidLink;
    String currentLink;
    String temp;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // Launch The Browser
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        // Enter URL
        driver.get("http://www.applicoinc.com");

        // Get all the links URL
        List<WebElement> ele = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
        System.out.println("size:" + ele.size());
        boolean isValid = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < ele.size(); i++) {

            isValid = getResponseCode(ele.get(i).getAttribute("href"));
            if (isValid) {
                System.out.println("ValidLinks:" + ele.get(i).getAttribute("href"));
                driver.get(ele.get(i).getAttribute("href"));
                List<WebElement> ele1 = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
                System.out.println("InsideSize:" + ele1.size());
                for (int j=0; j<ele1.size(); j++){
                    isValid = getResponseCode(ele.get(j).getAttribute("href"));
                    if (isValid) {
                        System.out.println("ValidLinks:" + ele.get(j).getAttribute("href"));
                    }
                    else{
                        System.out.println("InvalidLinks:"+ ele.get(j).getAttribute("href"));
                    }
                }

                } else {
                    System.out.println("InvalidLinks:"
                            + ele.get(i).getAttribute("href"));
                }

            }
        }
    }


    public static boolean getResponseCode(String urlString) {
        boolean isValid = false;
        try {
            URL u = new URL(urlString);
            HttpURLConnection h = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
            h.setRequestMethod("GET");
            h.connect();
            System.out.println(h.getResponseCode());
            if (h.getResponseCode() != 404) {
                isValid = true;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        return isValid;
    }

}
```

Comment: Actually what do you want to know? Is there any problem in your code? What's your question?

Answer (score 2):

I would keep it returning an int, and just have the MalformedURLException be a special case, returning -1.

```
public static int getResponseCode(String urlString) {
    try {
        URL u = new URL(urlString);
        HttpURLConnection h =  (HttpURLConnection)  u.openConnection();
        h.setRequestMethod("GET");
        h.connect();
        return h.getResponseCode();

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

EDIT: It seems you're sticking with the boolean approach, as I said before this has it's limitations but should work ok for demonstartion purposes.

There is no reason to find all elements a second time taking the approach you have. Try this:

```
// Get all the links
List<WebElement> ele = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
System.out.println("size:" + ele.size());
boolean isValid = false;
for (int i = 0; i < ele.size(); i++) {
    string nextHref = ele.get(i).getAttribute("href");
    isValid = getResponseCode(nextHref);
    if (isValid) {
        System.out.println("Valid Link:" + nextHref);

    }
    else {
        System.out.println("INVALID Link:" + nextHref);

    }
}
```

This is untested code, so if it does not work, please provide more detail than just saying 'it doesn't work', provide output & any stack traces/error messages if possible. Cheers

Comment: @lost this is what I have used but nothing works after Spending 4 hours. You're my only hope. Look at the coee

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that some of your href attribute contains expressions which are not identified as url's.
What comes immediately to mind is to use the try catch block to identify such url's.
Try the following piece of code.

```
package com.automation.test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Test {
    public static int invalidLink;
    String currentLink;
    String temp;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // Launch The Browser
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        // Enter Url
        driver.get("file:///home/sighil/Desktop/file");

        // Get all the links url
        List<WebElement> ele = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
        System.out.println("size:" + ele.size());
        boolean isValid = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < ele.size(); i++) {
            // System.out.println(ele.get(i).getAttribute("href"));
            isValid = getResponseCode(ele.get(i).getAttribute("href"));
            if (isValid) {
                System.out.println("ValidLinks:"
                        + ele.get(i).getAttribute("href"));
            } else {
                System.out.println("InvalidLinks:"
                        + ele.get(i).getAttribute("href"));
            }
        }

    }

    public static boolean getResponseCode(String urlString) {
        boolean isValid = false;
        try {
            URL u = new URL(urlString);
            HttpURLConnection h = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
            h.setRequestMethod("GET");
            h.connect();
            System.out.println(h.getResponseCode());
            if (h.getResponseCode() != 404) {
                isValid = true;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        return isValid;
    }

}
```

I have modified getResponseCode to return boolean values based on whether the url is valid(true) or invalid(false).

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for replying to my question. it doesn't work, it actually prints all the valid links written as "Invalid links"

Comment: my bad! I made a small mistake in the code. I have corrected it. Please try again.

Comment: This will only return false if it's a malformed URL or a 404 response. You should instead return true if it's a 200 response, or false for any other. Of course, this is still not perfect since redirects return in the 300's but it should get you looking in the right direction

Comment: hey @lost - its forcing me to changing getresponsecode to static and add a return statement

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am not aware about the different response codes. I just modified the code that @Learningcode posted.

Comment: @Learningcode, yes you should do that also. I have put the code in eclipse and corrected all errors now. Earlier I was just using notepad to write the code.

Comment: @lost still printing valid links as invalid links :(

Comment: The code posted above works for me. Have you copied the whole code correctly.

Comment: size:34
403
InvalidLinks:http://www.applicoinc.com/
403
InvalidLinks:http://www.applicoinc.com/services/
403

Comment: see this is what i am getting but this links are valid not invalid. they are not related to 404 error message

Comment: I have edited the code again. I think you should look at the response codes. 403 is the forbidden code and 404 is the Page not found. so >=404 should be fine. Please accept my answer. :)

Comment: @lost Thanks a lot! one last question, this code only find links on  the current web page but is there any way in selenium to find all the sub links too at the same time?

Comment: please explain what you meant by sublinks ? Do you want to click on a valid link and check the links on the new page ?

Comment: @lost exactly..right now i am just checking links on the main page. Is there any way to check valid link on the new page inside those main page and then links inside links of the links.

Comment: you could write a recursive function that loops through all your links. It has nothing to do with selenium. Just some logic :)

Comment: do you know how? :( i don't have much experience with java!!

Comment: try to do a little research... If you are stuck somewhere I can try to help you :) The comment section of this question has gone too long. Better post a new question when you are stuck.

Comment: @lost i have tried to do it yest please look at the edited code above and please help me out

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

List<String> brokenLinks = getBrokenURLs(driver, "http://mayurshah.in", 2, new ArrayList<String>());
for(String brokenLink : brokenLinks){
System.out.println(brokenLink);
}


}
public static List<String> getBrokenURLs(WebDriver driver, String appURL, int depth, List<String> links){
{
driver.navigate().to(appURL);
System.out.println("Depth is: " + depth);
while(depth > 0){
List<WebElement> linkElems = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
for(WebElement linkElement : linkElems)
if(!links.contains(linkElement))
links.add(linkElement.getAttribute("href"));
for(String link : links)
getBrokenURLs(driver, link, --depth, links);
}
}
return getBrokenURLs(driver, links, new ArrayList<String>()) ;
}

public static List<String> getBrokenURLs(WebDriver driver, List<String> links, List<String> brokenLinks){
{
for(String link : brokenLinks){
driver.navigate().to(link);
if(driver.getTitle().contains("404 Page Not Found")){
brokenLinks.add(link);
}
}
}
return brokenLinks ;
}
```

In above code, I am first getting list of URLs from the first page. Now I am navigating to the first link of the IInd page and getting all URLs, this way I will keep on storing all URL by going to each page one by one, till depth is mentioned.

After collecting all URLs, I will verify validity of each URL one by one and return List of URLs with 404 page.

Hope that helps!

src:
https://softwaretestingboard.com/qna/1380/how-to-find-broken-links-images-from-page-using-webdriver#axzz4wM3UEZtq

Answer (score 0):

In web application we have to verify all the links whether they are broken means the after clicking on link ‘page not found’ page displays.
Below is the code:

```
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver; 
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class VerifyLinks {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(); 
        driver.manage().window().maximize(); 
        driver.get("https://www.google.co.in");
        List< WebElement > allLink = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a")); 
        System.out.println("Total links are " + allLink.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < allLink.size(); i++) {
        WebElement ele = allLink.get(i); 
        String url = ele.getAttribute("href"); 
        verifyLinkActive(url);
    }
}
    public static void verifyLinkActive(String linkurl) {
        try {
           URL url = new URL(linkurl);
           HttpURLConnection httpUrlConnect = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
           httpUrlConnect.setConnectTimeout(3000); 
           httpUrlConnect.connect();
           if (httpUrlConnect.getResponseCode() == 200) {
              System.out.println(linkurl + " - " + httpUrlConnect.getResponseMessage());
           }
              if (httpUrlConnect.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_NOT_FOUND) {
                  System.out.println(linkurl + " - " + httpUrlConnect.getResponseMessage() 
                                     + " - " + HttpURLConnection.HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
              }
       }
       catch (Exception e) {
       }
   }
}
```

For more tutorial visit 
https://www.jbktutorials.com/selenium

Answer (score 0):

**Steps:**
1. Open a browser and navigate to [TestURL](https://link.testproject.io/bsg)
2. Grab all the links from the entire page
3. Check HTTP status code for all the links grabbed in step 2 (status 200 is OK, others are broken)
**Selenium WebDriver Java code:**

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("<TestURL>");
List<WebElement> total_links = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
System.out.println("Total Number of links: " + total_links.size());
for(int i = 0; i < total_links.size(); i++){
String url = total_links.get(i).getAttribute("href");
int resp_Code = 0;
try{
HttpResponse urlresp = new DefaultHttpClient().execute(new HttpGet(url));
resp_Code = urlresp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
}catch(Exception e){
}
if(resp_Code >= 400){
System.out.println(url + " is a broken link");
}
else{
System.out.println(url + " is a valid link");
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  //allHref -for count of actual active links==after if statement filter
List<WebElement> allHref = new ArrayList<WebElement>();
    List<WebElement> linklist = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));

    for (int i = 0; i < linklist.size(); i++) {
        if (linklist.get(i).getAttribute("href").contains("https:")
                && linklist.get(i).getAttribute("href") != null) {
            System.out.println(linklist.get(i).getAttribute("href"));
            
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(linklist.get(i).getAttribute("href"))
                    .openConnection();
            connection.connect();
            String response = connection.getResponseMessage();
            connection.disconnect();
            System.out.println(linklist.get(i).getAttribute("href") + "R=e=s=p=o=n=s=e=>" + response);
            allHref.add(linklist.get(i));
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: Please add some explanation as to why this is a good solution to this problem.